# how to rotate button background image only

Tags: html, css, sass

i click my button the button back ground image rotate 180 ,because the button is act like accordion click time open a div my html content are

```
<button class="bann"aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="bann">
<span class="bann-text">open</span>
</button>
```

i have only one image down-arrow.svg it will rotate and show in click time,the scss are

```
.bann {
      border: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      background: url("../../images/down-arrow.svg") no-repeat center/1.3128205128ex 0.8ex;

      &::after {
         width: 21.312821ex;
         
      }
&.bann[aria-expanded=true]{
      background: url("../../images/down-arrow.svg") no-repeat center/1.3128205128ex 0.8ex;
      content:"";
      transform:rotate(180deg) !important;
    
   }
```

i use the above scss but the content "open" and image are rotate why ,how to rotate image only?

Comment: Andrew please provide a link to a code snippet or use the inbuilt code snippet tool to create a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you or any problems, let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix this is by rotating back the span. I created this test based on your code.

index.html (arrow.svg in same folder as index.html)

```
<head>
    <style>
        .bann {
            border: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            background: url(arrow.svg) no-repeat center/1.3128205128ex 0.8ex;
            padding: 40px;
            width: 21.312821ex;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .bann[aria-expanded=true] {
            background: url(arrow.svg) no-repeat center/1.3128205128ex 0.8ex;
            transform: rotate(180deg) !important;
        }

        .bann[aria-expanded=true] span {
            transform: rotate(180deg) !important;
        }

        .bann-text {
            display: block;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="bann" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="bann">
        <span class="bann-text">te&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;st</span>
    </button>
</body>
```